# Powershell stops working when using -ea with Add-PSSnapin

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

i just encountered this strange behaviour:

The following line causes powershell to stop working:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010 -Erroraction Silentlycontinue
```

while the following works fine:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
```

This is the problem signature found in the Eventviewer:

> P1: powershell.exe
>
> P2: 6.3.9600.17090
>
> P3: System.NullReferenceException
>
> P4: System.TypeInitializationException
>
> P5: unknown
>
> P6: oft.Exchange.Diagnostics.SystemTraceControl.Update
>
> P7: unknown

Does anyone have a clue why this happens? The system runs on Server 2012R2

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't tell you why this is happening, but I can tell you that Microsoft does not support managing Exchange using a generic PS session with that snapin added.

Comment: @mjolinor thanks i know and i´m fine with that

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue on Server 2012 R2. I was able to get it working by leveraging the -name argument.

```
Add-PSSnapin -name "Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010"
```

Comment: sadly i cant confirm since i dont work in the environment where this occured anymore, if someone confirms it i will gladly accept your answer